# How to port this application as a web service?

Tags: java, web-applications

I have a java application which doing some logic... ...
But the java application is only a .jar application. But I would like to let it become an application on the web....I can get the param from the user, but how can I pass the param from user, and put it into my .jar, and process and output the result to the user??

notice that the .jar application is only a console application, which don't need a user interface, only cmd lines communicated with it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have source code? If you do, you can expose the services using JAX-WS annotations. JAX-WS is available in J2SE6. 
Take a look at this: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jax_ws_2/

You then have to package the modified code to a WAR instead of a jar, because your application now becomes a web application. Then it will have to be hosted in an application server - Tomcat for example.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at [Metro](http://metro.java.net/).